# Octave: Not treating one element JSON array as an array

Tags: arrays, json, octave

Octave **jsondecode** treats one element array as **not** an array, for example:

```
j1 = jsondecode ('{"foo": [42]}')
```

and

```
j2 = jsondecode ('{"foo": 42}')
```

both **jsonencode** to same thing:

```
ans = {"foo":42}
```

How can I make it encode to **following**:

```
ans = {"foo":[42]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too clear which direction is the problem in your case, but perhaps this is what you're after?

```
tmp = struct()
tmp.foo = {42}
jsonencode( tmp )
% ans = {"foo":[42]}
```

or as a one-liner:

```
jsonencode( struct( 'foo', {{42}} ) )
% ans = {"foo":[42]}
```

<sub>Note: read the documentation of 'struct' regarding why `{{42}}` is needed here instead of simply `{42}`</sub>

Unfortunately, in terms of the other way round, then yes, the decoding of both '42', and '[42]' will yield the same octave object, since in octave a scalar is simply an array of size [1,1]. So if you need to specify a wrapping array around such a value, you'll have to convert it into a cell manually first, before encoding into a json string.